# On Cisco routers, is it possible to have equal cost multipath static routes ?

Tags: routes, load-balancing, cisco

On Cisco routers, is it possible to have equal cost multipath static routes ?

If so, how ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this should be on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. IOS router with will load share between static/default routes. Just enter two static routes to the same destination, pointing to different next-hops:

`ip route 10.3.1.1 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.2`
`ip route 10.3.1.1 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.6`

(these nex-hops of course should know a way to the destination address/net)
Load sharing behavior is dependent on packet switching method used for some particular flow.

With IOS fast switching - you can load-share only `per-destination` (ip-src - ip-dst pair).
With CEF you can use two load sharing algorythms - `per-packet` and `per-destination`.

Use this global config command to turn CEF on:

`ip cef`

Use these commands on the incomming interface to change CEF load sharing algorythm:

`ip load-sharing per-packet`
 `ip load-sharing per-destination`

Use this command to check load sharing status for some particular prefix:

`sho ip cef <prefix> detail`